# Error in uploading file to a server using Phonegap file transfer

Tags: android, file, file-upload, cordova, file-transfer

I am using phonegap to upload file to a server. I am making android app which takes picture and send to server. I am getting error

> "Response  Parse error  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in this line"

I am also pasting the code

this is my phonegap code.

```js
 navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, {
                        quality : 75,
                        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                        sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                        mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA,
                        allowEdit : true,
                        targetWidth: 100,
                        targetHeight: 100
                    });
```

and

```php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'/TeleNoc Sites Images/'.basename($_FILES['file']['name']));
```

This is my upload script to catch the file on server

Answer (score 0):

A common reason to get the 'unexpected T_STRING' error is a missing semi colon in the line before.

Dan